How to extract crack contours from binary images?
My images are like this；

I want to extract the contours like this:

My Python code is:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc("font", family='SimHei')
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
im = cv2.imread(r'Desktop\file\lunwen\test\image1\1381_8.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) im = cv2.threshold(im, 128, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
result = np.zeros_like(im, dtype='uint32')
diff = np.diff(im.astype(np.int8), axis=1)
y, x_min = np.nonzero(diff == 1) 
_, x_max = np.nonzero(diff == -1)
width_list = x_max - x_min
print('max_width:', np.max(width_list))
print('min_width:', np.min(width_list))
print('mean_width:', np.mean(width_list))
for i in range(x_min.size):
    result[y[i], x_min[i]:x_max[i]] = width_list[i]
viridis = plt.cm.viridis
newcolors = viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
newcolors[0, :] = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.title('Crack Contour')
cax = plt.imshow(result, cmap=newcmp)
plt.axis('off')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, fraction=0.03, pad=0.06,label='Width', orientation='vertical')
plt.savefig('result_with_colorbar.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
plt.show()

When I use the above 'original' images it seems to not work out. There is a bug like
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Test.py", line 30, in <module>
    width_list = x_max - x_min  
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (797,) (800,) 


Where did you get that code?  x_min will have the indices of the elements that are equal to 1.  x_max will have the indices of the elements that are equal to -1.  Unless those arrays are the same size, which they are not, you can't subtract them.

@TimRoberts It's by my fellow written, can I add the |x_max - x_min|, something like mathematics?

You do not show your result.  Also your desired result looks nothing like your input.  Please post your result and say why it is not acceptable.  Does your code not work? If not, where does it fail?  Show your error messages, if so.

It does no good to use someone else code if you do not understand it and cannot debug it. Have you done any research to try to learn what your friend wrote? Have you taken any Python/OpenCV courses (online or otherwise)?

The error message say that x_max and x_min do not have the same shapes. So figure out why that is!

Post your input image so others can use it to test the code and figure out why you get an error.

There are more non-zero values with diff == 1 than with diff == -1. So x_max is smaller than x_min.  That causes your error as the two arrays are different shape.

Are you only doing this for the purposes of plotting, or is there a second processing step you haven't shown? I think I see a hard-coded 'white' for non-crack pixels; would you be looking for an array that has NaN on those pixels?

If x_max has the value [2,4,6,8] and x_min has the value [3,5], what would the result of x_max - x_min be?

There may be a simpler way, but let's be careful and assert (commented) as we go:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


image = np.array(
    Image.open(fp='cracked.jpg').convert(mode='1')
)

# Add an outer black boundary for sane boundary conditions
black_col = np.zeros_like(image[:, :1])
image = np.hstack((black_col, image, black_col))

diff = np.diff(a=image.astype(np.int8), axis=1)
diff_y, diff_x = diff.nonzero()

diff_x = diff_x.reshape((-1, 2))
# assert np.all(diff_x[:, 0] < diff_x[:, 1]), 'Monotonic start/stop'
# diff_y = diff_y.reshape(diff_x.shape)
# assert np.all(diff_y[:, 0] == diff_y[:, 1]), 'Start/stop on same row'
# assert np.all(+1 == diff[diff_y[:, 0], diff_x[:, 0]]), 'Start rise'
# assert np.all(-1 == diff[diff_y[:, 1], diff_x[:, 1]]), 'Stop fall'

widths = diff_x[:, 1] - diff_x[:, 0]
width_image = np.full(shape=image.shape, fill_value=np.nan, dtype=float)
width_image[image] = np.repeat(widths, widths)

plt.imshow(width_image)
plt.show()

This produces an image with NaN on non-crack pixels and the width on crack pixels:

